# Nodejs Selenium-webdriver Selecting Particular <select> element if there are 2 elements that have the same ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nodejs

On a single page on our website, there are two elements that are.. very very similar:

"A"

```
<select class="form-control custom-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="SelectEU" name="SelectEU" required="">
```

"B"

```
<select class="form-control custom-select ng-untouched ng-pristine" id="SelectEU" name="SelectEU" required="" disabled="">
```

the differences are :

A has class `ng-pristine`

B has property `disabled=""`

How can I click on the first select, A, then select a particular value??

I have tried the following to no avail..

I tried selecting  based on `ng-pristine`

```
element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control custom-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid']"))[0];
```

I tried selecting based on [0]..

```
element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='SelectEU']"))[0];
```

I tried selecting by the text (A contains the text "Electric Utility"

```
element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@id='SelectEU' and text()='Electric Utility']"))[0];
```

It all has the error: `no such element exists`

Comment: You almost had it. The first match is [1] not [0]. `element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='SelectEU'][1]"));`

Comment: Alternatively you could use the original locator with the [0] outside of the path, but make the findElement plural: `element = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//option[@id='SelectEU' and text()='Electric Utility']"))[0];`

Comment: Oh my.. I see my error. I mistyped `element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='SelectEU']"))[0];` it should have been
`element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='SelectEU'][1]"));` 

Very grateful. I would gladly accept your answer and upvote sir if you provide it here...

Comment: I wasn't 100% positive that my solution would work, which is why I offered it as a comment instead of an answer.  I appreciate your acknowledgement.

Comment: @BillHileman on your second point in this thread, "alternatively you could use the original locator with the [0] outside..." How would you scroll to such an element? `await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);` returns an error for me..

Comment: I merely meant that by adding an 's' to .findElement (.findElements) it returns an arraylist which could then be accessed as a zero-based array.  I don't use nodejs or javascript, so I'm not sure what the syntax would be.  In java, if I have an array of webelements, it have to do element.get(0) (and I might even be wrong about that, but I don't think so).  I'd have to defer to the javascript experts on what needs to be done for your scrollintoview.  I might have a javascript routine that does that but I will have to check tomorrow from work.

Comment: @BillHileman would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. The first match is [1] not [0].

Change your line to:

```
element = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='SelectEU'][1]"));
```

> Edit: Regarding your second question in your main post comments

I do not have the nodejs knowledge to provide you the exact syntax of scrolling an element into view, however this is the JavaScript routine I use in Java to accomplish that requirement:

```
/** 
 * Scroll a web element into view
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param ele - WebElement
 */
public void scrollIntoView(WebElement ele) {

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + ele.getLocation().x + 
                                                                "," + ele.getLocation().y + ")");

}
```

Comment: added extra lines to the code @BillHileman, but now it works :)